# Swift function execution order

Tags: swift, multithreading, function, asynchronous, synchronization

I'm trying to load sleep data from healthkit.
after retrieving some data, I converted it into Double type to use chart, and reflected them on setChart function.
But here's some problem.

To successfully show on chart, my function should executed in order.
Ideal order is : retrieve data, convert data -> setchart

but the order is not kept.

I read some articles about dispatchqueue, but still I can't solve the problem.

What should I do to solve this problem? \

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //선행작업
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).sync {
        print("1")
        self.retrieveSleepAnalysis()

    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).sync {
        print("2")
        self.recentSleepStartHourDouble = self.stringTimeToDouble(stringTime: self.recentSleepStartHour)
        self.wakeUp = self.wakeupTimeCalcuation(start: self.recentSleepStartHourDouble, end: self.resultToSleepAmount)
       
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
     //   self.recentSleepStartHourDouble = self.stringTimeToDouble(stringTime: self.recentSleepStartHour)
     //   self.wakeUp = self.wakeupTimeCalcuation(start: self.recentSleepStartHourDouble, end: self.resultToSleepAmount)
        self.setChart(days: self.recentSleepDate.reversed(), sleepTimes: self.recentSleepStartHourDouble.reversed(), wakeupTimes:



public func retrieveSleepAnalysis() {

    // first, we define the object type we want
    if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis) {
       // print(sleepType)
        // Use a sortDescriptor to get the recent data first
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)
        
        // we create our query with a block completion to execute
        
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sleepType, predicate: nil, limit: 7, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, tmpResult, error) -> Void in
            
            if error != nil {
                // something happened
                return
            }
            if let result = tmpResult {
                              
                for item in result {
                    
                    if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                        
                        let value = (sample.value == HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.inBed.rawValue) ? "InBed" : "Asleep"
                  
                        print("Healthkit sleep: \(sample.startDate) \(sample.endDate) - value: \(value)")
                        let sleepHour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: sample.startDate)
                        print("현지시각으로 잠든시간 \(sleepHour)")
                        
                        if sleepHour < 19 && sleepHour > 12{
                            print("낮잠")
                        }
                        
                        else{
                            self.resultToSleepAmount.append(CFDateGetTimeIntervalSinceDate(sample.endDate as CFDate, sample.startDate as CFDate)/3600)
                            let myDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                            myDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM / dd"
                            myDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ko_KR")
                            let sleepDate = myDateFormatter.string(from: sample.startDate)
                            self.recentSleepDate.append(sleepDate)
                            
                            let myHourFormatter = DateFormatter()
                            myHourFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"
                            myHourFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ko_KR")
                            let sleepStartHour = myHourFormatter.string(from: sample.startDate)
                            self.recentSleepStartHour.append(sleepStartHour)
                            print("잠든 시간은 몇시몇분? \(sleepStartHour)")
                            let sleepEndHour = myHourFormatter.string(from: sample.endDate)
                            self.recentSleepEndHour.append(sleepEndHour)
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                    print("total amount of sleep time : \(self.resultToSleepAmount), 현재 크기는 : \(self.resultToSleepAmount.count)")
                }
            }
        }
        // finally, we execute our query
        healthStore.execute(query)

        
    }
```

Comment: Copy/paste code, not screenshot. You have async code I guess (since it's HealthKit), so implement a closure/callback and call the next method ONCE you get the result. But show more code, especially the `retrieveSleepAnalysis()`

Comment: I added my codes,, do you mean that  I should study completion handler to solve this? Since swift is new language to me, I do not know concept of closure now.